# CakePHP2でAWSのS3プラグインを使用しているのですがアップロードがうまくいきません。

Tags: cakephp, aws

お世話になっております。
ご回答ありがとうございます。
現在、ご紹介いただいた https://github.com/robmcvey/cakephp-amazon-s3 のプラグインを使用しているのですが、

```
Error: Call to a member function put() on null  
File: /var/www/html/cakephp-2.6.4/app/Controller/UploadsController.php  
Line: 25
```

という、エラーが発生しています。 `$AmazonS3->put('/*****/files/');` の部分です。
Readmeの通りに記述しましたがうまくいかないのですが、記述の仕方がまちがっているのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
   public function add() {
            if ($this->request->is('post')) {

                    $tmp = $this->request->data['Upload']['file']['tmp_name'];
                    if(is_uploaded_file($tmp)) {
                            $filename = basename($this->request->data['Upload']['file']['name']);
                            $file = WWW_ROOT.'files'.DS.$filename;

                            // S3にファイル保存
                            $AmazonS3->put('/*****/files/');  // *****はパケット名、filesは作成したフォルダ

                            if (move_uploaded_file($tmp, $file)) {
                                    $this->Upload->create();
                                    $this->request->data['Upload']['filename'] = $filename;
                                    if ($this->Upload->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
                                            $this->Session->setFlash(__('アップロードしました。'));
                                            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                                    } else {
                                            $this->Session->setFlash(__('アップロードできませんでした。'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$AmazonS3`が作成されていません。

READMEをもう一度よく読んでみましょう。

```
App::uses('AmazonS3', 'AmazonS3.Lib');
$AmazonS3 = new AmazonS3(array('{access key}', '{secret key}', '{bucket name}'));
```

とあるはずです。

Comment: お世話になっております。
上記のコードを追加しまして、再度アップロードいたしましたら、
The localPath you set does not exist
とエラーがでてしまいました。
localPathとは、/Lib/AmazonS3.php 49行目
`
    /**
     * Absolute path to ur local file
     * @var string
     */ 
     public $localPath = '';
`

ここの部分なのですが、絶対パスを記述書いてとのことだと思いますが、
S3側のフォルダではなくてEC2のフォルダを記述しないといけないのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: はい。`put($localPath)`はS3側ではなくて、サーバー側のファイルパスを与えてください。この質問のコードだと`$tmp`が実ファイルパスのはずです。

Comment: `public $localPath = 'webroot/files/';`
とサーバにアップされるパスを入力しましたが、同じエラーがでています。s3を使わないときのファイルアップ時のパスを記述しましたが、$tmpのファイルパスは実際に保存されるフォルダとは違うのでしょうか？

Comment: /Lib/AmazonS3.phpを編集したのなら間違いです。 `$AmazonS3->put($tmp);` としてください。また、"パス"はディレクトリのことではありません。ファイルの位置のことです。この場合、ファイル名まで含めてください。
アップロードファイルは、`move_upload_file`でファイルを移動するまでは`tmp_name`の場所にテンポラリファイルとして存在します。
質問のコードでは、`$AmazonS3->put()`の呼び出し位置が`move_upload_file`より前にありますので、ファイルはまだテンポラリにあります。テンポラリファイルはファイル名が実ファイル名と異なりますので、ファイル名をアップロードされたものにしたい場合は、`move_upload_file`実行後に`$AmazonS3->put($file)`として、アップロードしましょう。

Comment: お世話になっております。 `$Amazon->put($tmp);`というのは、一時的に$tmpに置いたファイルをs3にputするということですね。理解が足りませんでした。 `$Amazon->put($tmp);`を消して、 `$Amazon->put($file);`を`move_upload_file`の後に記述したのですが、Could not complete the HTTP requestとエラーがでます。これはS3と通信がされていないということでしょうか？根本的に設定が違うのでしょうか？ファイルはapp/webroot/filesにアップされていますが、s3に移動していません。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: https://github.com/robmcvey/cakephp-amazon-s3/blob/master/Lib/AmazonS3.php#L283 の部分での例外ですね。デバッガか`debug()`を仕込んでSocketExceptionの内容を見てみるとヒントが見つかるかもしれません。

Comment: お世話になっております。
Stack Trace
`APP/Plugin/AmazonS3/Lib/AmazonS3.php line 155 → AmazonS3->handleRequest(array)`

`APP/Controller/UploadsController.php line 29 → AmazonS3->put(string)`

`[internal function] → UploadsController->add()`

`CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php line 490 → ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(UploadsController, array)`

`CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 193 → Controller->invokeAction(CakeRequest)`

`CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 167 → Dispatcher->_invoke(UploadsController, CakeRequest)`

`APP/webroot/index.php line 118 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)`

Comment: 上記のように表示されており、配列に入っていないのがみられるのですが、add function内のアップロード記述がそもそもおかしいということのなのでしょうか？何度も申し訳ないですがよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: SocketExceptionのメッセージ内容はどうなっていますか？それによってどの部分で失敗しているのかがわかります。（APIの呼び出し失敗、認証失敗、権限が足りない、存在しないパスにアップロードしようとしているetc...

Comment: `object(SocketException) {
 [protected] _attributes => array()
 [protected] _messageTemplate => ''
 [protected] _responseHeaders => null
 [protected] message => 'php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known'
 [protected] code => (int) 0
 [protected] file => '/var/www/html/cakephp-2.6.4/lib/Cake/Network/CakeSocket.php'
 [protected] line => (int) 161
}`
とでています。DNSの設定でしょうか？

Comment: ホスト名が解決できていませんね。バケット名は正しいですか？`$AmazonS3->bucket` の値を確認してください。また`バケット名.s3.amazonaws.com`の名前解決がサーバー上からできるかも確認してみてください。